# How to retrieve all duplicate emails using postgres and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I found I have many users objects with same email address. I need to delete those duplicates.

```
User.select(:email).group(:email).having('COUNT(email) > 1')
```

I tried the following query (which is similar to a [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621845/how-to-do-this-group-activerecord-query-in-postgres/17622755?noredirect=1#comment25655125_17622755)). but I get an empty array. Any idea why?

```
2.0.0p247 :277 > User.select(:email).group(:email).having('COUNT(email) > 1')
  User Load (7801.4ms)  SELECT email FROM "users" GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
  EXPLAIN (0.4ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT email FROM "users" GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
EXPLAIN for: SELECT email FROM "users"  GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
                                 QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=676876.34..739393.66 rows=3125866 width=22)
   Filter: (count(email) > 1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=676876.34..684691.01 rows=3125866 width=22)
         Sort Key: email
         ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..147342.66 rows=3125866 width=22)
(5 rows)

 => []
```

***Update*** Also, if I try the solution by Dave it doesnt work either.

```
2.0.0p247 :004 > User.select('email, count(email)').group('email').having('count(email) > 1')
  User Load (7858.0ms)  SELECT email, count(email) FROM "users" GROUP BY email HAVING count(email) > 1
  EXPLAIN (0.4ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT email, count(email) FROM "users" GROUP BY email HAVING count(email) > 1
EXPLAIN for: SELECT email, count(email) FROM "users"  GROUP BY email HAVING count(email) > 1
                                 QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=676876.34..747208.33 rows=3125866 width=22)
   Filter: (count(email) > 1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=676876.34..684691.01 rows=3125866 width=22)
         Sort Key: email
         ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..147342.66 rows=3125866 width=22)
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
User.select('email, count(email)').group('email').having('count(email) > 1')
```

Comment: Such approach will give you the list of uniq emails not the duplicates.

Comment: My fault. I fixed it. Cheers.

Comment: Doesn't work, same result. Please see my updated question with result.

Comment: Tried on my FB using pure SQL and it works. I don't know what you expect to get from AR, but you won't get users with duplicate emails - just user instances instantiated with found emails.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
duplicates = User.where(email: User.pluck(:email).detect{ |e| User.pluck(:email).count(e) > 1 })
```

This however is in memory, and can get slow. There is probably a better way to do this with active record, but I could not find that with a quick google.

Comment: This is a totally impossible query to run. Even with indexes in place, takes an average of 3000ms per row. There are over 3 million rows !

Comment: Well, there you go. Not too fast as I mentioned. Too bad it was that slow.